# What is the answer to this homework about maps and collections?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

1. Maps collection is referred to an dictionary because of the way it works.
2. Each entry into a maps collection involves a pair of objects.
3. In a maps collection, an object associates the key which determines where the  object is stored in the map.
4. The key object in the maps collection can be duplicated.
5. A stack which has Last In First Out storage mechanism can be considered as a maps collection.

I think #1,#2,#3 and #5 are Correct in above, but I have doubt with #5. Am I correct?

Comment: @dantuch i have doubt with that. not sure it correct or not

Comment: It would be a better question if you explain why you think those options would be correct. It is homework, so it won't be good to give you the answer so easily, instead guide you to the answer.

Comment: @BharatSinha i'm not added it. some one has edited my post and, he did that. i have correct it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza  i know #1,#2,#3 are correct according to my lecture notes. but i have a doubt with #5

Comment: @Bishan Why **could** #5 be correct in your opinion and why not?

Comment: Then explain your doubts and people will start to guide you, the question looks like "is 5 right or not?" so I could post an answer saying "yes" or "no".

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Map may be used in some way as a stack

Comment: Voting to close as "too localized" as part of the homework cleanup.

Comment: Leaving the homework tag on until closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack, as you said, is a Last In First Out operation.

Map, on the other hand, provides you to keep pair of elements(key,value) which can be uniquely identified by the keys.

AFAIK, #5 doesn't holds true. Until you want to use the order of elements pushed and popped as the key, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's true that a map may be used in some way as a "stack" - but I think what the question aims at is the other way round. Using a LIFO Stack like a map or dictionary is certainly not possible.